# Como usar a parte de User do Django em um model?

Tags: python, django

Estou fazendo um blog e surgiu a duvida, tem como usar o sistema de usuários do *Django* para fazer uma *ForeignKey* na minha variável author ?

```
from django.db import models


class Category(DatastampMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Categoria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categorias'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(DatastampMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = # ?????????
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Gente para quem tava com a mesma duvida ta ai a solução, é só fazer o import e usar normalmente (*from django.contrib.auth.models import User*)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(DatastampMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Categoria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categorias'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(DatastampMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma outra possibilidade, só não sei se atende ao que você precisava.

```
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```